# Why can't i see php call in Mozilla's Net tab?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox

```
     $('#registerForm').submit(
        function()
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            callAjaxSubmitMethod(this);
        }
    );  

    function callAjaxSubmitMethod(form)
   {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "lib/registration_validate.php",
    data: $("#registerForm").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
            {
                console.log("cominggggg");
                alert("s"+response.status);
            },
    error:function(response)
            {
                alert("e"+response.status);
            },
    complete:function(response)
            {
                console.log("Completed.");
            }       

     });
  }
```

This is how i am sending data to my php page.

```
    <?php
     include 'configdb.php';
     session_start();
     global $connection;
     echo "oops";
     if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['email']!='' && $_POST['password']!='')
    {   
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE emailID = '$email'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1) or die("Oops");
    $response = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
    {
    $response['status']='Email Already Exists';
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
   }
   }?>
```

I am just processing for duplicate email registration. If ia run this code in my chrome, i can see `php` in net tab. I can see `completed` in console and `e200` in alert.

In my mozilla browser, i don't get any console strings, alerts. I din't get `php page call` in Net tab too.

I just cleared cache too. So it's not coming from cache too. I cleared `localStorage` due to `out of memory` error in my mozilla.

I don't even understand this behaviour. No idea to how to debug further.

Comment: I think you better use Firebug in FireFox, if you don't get an alert and you get one in chrome maybe your syntax is not correct? Here is the link to firebug: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I am using firebug only

Comment: have you get your code already working?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit, it seems that chrome accept the way you have made it, firefox does not.

So instead of this:

```
$('#registerForm').submit(
    function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        callAjaxSubmitMethod(this);
    }
);
```

Do this:

```
 $('#registerForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        callAjaxSubmitMethod(this);
    }
);
```

Notice I added also the event param, you were missing that.